# Thread does not stop after interruption

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem that a threads do not stop after I call `.interrupt()` method. There is a code snippet

```
for (Thread t : letters.getThreads()) t.start();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

for (Thread t : letters.getThreads()) t.interrupt();
```

There `getThreads()` method is from class Letters (letters is an object of the class) and it returns array of Thread objects. Here you have body of the method from Letters class:

```
public Thread[] getThreads() {
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[letters.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread( () -> {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        System.out.print("a");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
        }
        ,"Thread " + letters[i]); //letters[] is a local array.            
        }
    return threads;
}
```

and in this case I described, threads do not stop working, but when I do everything in main mathod ( array of Threads objects ) it works properly. Why is this happening?

Comment: print your console output

Comment: What do you think `new` does?

Comment: Oh god I see it now. I just created new threads and interrupted them instead of iterrupting the old ones. Thanks :)

Comment: P.S.:  Interrupting a thread does does not stop it.  All it does is set a flag and then, if the thread was in a blocking call (e.g., waiting for I/O or for a timed event) then it causes the blocking call to throw an exception.  If the thread is just flat-out running, computing something, then the interruption does not even throw an exception:  All it does is set the flag.  If you want your thread to stop and take notice, then it has to _check_ the flag.  E.g., `if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the getThreads() method, you create new threads. First call create new threads and started them. However the 2nd call also create new threads but never started hence interrupt non-running threads doesn't work?